# Google Directions, bug in common.js?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've been using the Google Directions api for a few days. My javascript code worked fine for a day or two, but then late one night it didn't work. In the FF console:

> TypeError: b is undefined[Learn More]  common.js:49:155

FWIW, this is common.js line 49 (NOT my code!):

> e;_.sb(d);window.gm_authFailure&&window.gm_authFailure()}El();c(b)})})};*.cn=function(a,b){a.b();return function(){var c=this,d=arguments;a.f(function(a){a&&b.apply(c,d)})}};dn=function(a,b,c,d,e,f){this.b=new Km;this.b.setUrl(c.substring(0,1024));f&&(this.b.data[8]=f);d?this.b.data[1]=d:e&&(this.b.data[2]=e);this.b.data[4]=0;this.b.data[5]=1;this.l=a;this.j=b};en=function(a){Dl=!0;0!=a.getStatus()||*.Aj(a,2)||($m(),*.P(a,3)&&*.sb(_.P(a,3)));El()};

I'm pretty sure the error is related to this call in my client-side app:

> directionsService.route(myRequest,myCallback);

It's a Google method that asks Google for directions from one geographical point to another.

Here's my code: https://pastebin.com/AtcFQ9tZ

```
ost.setPickupCharge = function(position)
{
  var p = ost.pickup;
  p.lat = position.coords.latitude;
  p.lng = position.coords.longitude; /* alert("lat: " + lat + "\nlng: " + lng); */

  var request = {
    origin: '45 East University Avenue, Champaign, IL',
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat,p.lng),
    provideRouteAlternatives: false,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }
  function showCost(result, status) {
    if (status != 'OK') { alert(status) }
    else {
      var route = result.routes[0]; 
      var dists = route.legs.map(function(leg) { return leg.distance.value });  p.miles = 0.00062137 * A.sum(dists);
      var times = route.legs.map(function(leg) { return leg.duration.value });  p.minutes = A.sum(times) / 60;
      p.charge = .6 * p.miles + .15 * p.minutes;
      alert("pickup charge = $" + p.charge);
      ost.showRideButtons();
    }
  }
  directionsService.route(request,ost.showCost);
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question. You can read more about [how to ask a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: common.js line 49 IS the relevant code. What else do you want?

Comment: I mean edit your question to actually include your code - probably the method that contains `directionsService.route(myRequest,myCallback);
` and the `directionsService.route` method itself at least

Comment: You'll have to ask a Google dev for the source to directionsService.route(). Here's the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#RenderingDirections

Comment: My mistake I did not know that wasn't yours: I'd like the other option from my previous comment if that's possible: the method that contains `directionsService.route(myRequest,myCallback); `

Comment: Here's my code: https://pastebin.com/AtcFQ9tZ

Comment: Could someone please explain their downvote so I can find a more appropriate venue for this question? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would suggest that you inspect the request variable before calling the directionsService. There may be some invalid values which are causing the error.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the bug in my own code. It's an undefined callback (ost.showCost instead of the local showCost).